# How to remove this red box

Tags: eclipse

[image]

While programming in Eclipse, suddenly a red box overlays some of my code.
How can I remove it?

Comment: Possibly a "code coverage" plug-in highlighting

Comment: Check your Annotations preference page, under Text Editors, and see what kind of annotation Highlights text that color for you.